# Program crashes with NSException when trying to implement UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I dragged a UISearchBar onto my xib, hooked it up to my file's owner for delegate and searchBar as an outlet. I get a crash when I change to the view with the search bar. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, do I need to implement the search bar delegate methods before it stops crashing?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController {
 @private UISearchBar *searchBar_;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end

#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@implementation ThirdViewController
 @synthesize
  searchBar = searchBar_;

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [super viewDidLoad];
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

  // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
  [super viewDidUnload];

  // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
  // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [searchBar_ release], searchBar_ = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you add the crash log? There is nothing wrong with the `dealloc` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a problem with how it was hooked up in the xib file and had nothing to do with the .h/.m files.

Answer (score -1):

This is the problem with the dealloc .There you have released the searchBar.You didn't alloc it.So don't release it.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure that's how you're supposed to do it. As it's set as a property with retain. But anyways, even after I've removed it I still have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Why did you release your searchBar, you never allocated any memory to it so you cant release it.